get item float by steam market with selenium and extension
enter image description here
enter image description here
hello everyone, I want to get float data from the steam page, before expanding it to 100 items, for this you need to use the csfloat extension
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/csfloat-market-checker/jjicbefpemnphinccgikpdaagjebbnhgenter code here
this extension loads data asynchronously and the usual methods of searching by class name or xpath do not work.
example of a subject
https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/M249%20%7C%20Submerged%20%28Field-Tested%29
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
chrome_options.add_extension('cs2float.crx') #https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/csfloat-market-checker/jjicbefpemnphinccgikpdaagjebbnhg
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 200)

driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Field-Tested%29?filter=')
y = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'float-row-wrapper')
for s in y:
    print(s)


Have you tried explicitly waiting for the element you are trying to handle?
